# The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program on cygwin

Tags: c++, cmake

I found some other topic has the same problem but it seems the solution for me

I'm trying to install FC4SC library (https://github.com/amiq-consulting/fc4sc)

And this is tested by google test. when I do following the guideline

I used the command:

```
cmake -DBUILD_GTEST=ON BUILD_GTEST -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..
```

And then it showed like this

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.14.5/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /cygdrive/d/SystemC/7_UVM/Coverage/fc4sc-master/test/googletest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make.exe cmTC_7a5cd/fast




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/d/SystemC/7_UVM/Coverage/fc4sc-master/test/googletest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/d/SystemC/7_UVM/Coverage/fc4sc-master/test/googletest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I tried to reinstall gcc and some other component that they are related but It didn't work

Following is the cmake Error output:[image]

Comment: So what is your question? `I used the command:` why? From where? What is meant by the `..`? What guideline? Don't you think it's relevant to mention what platform are you on? Why are you using cmake?

Comment: That repo does not mention cmake anywhere. Where did you find the guideline you're following?

Comment: This is the guideline, on page 13 of https://github.com/amiq-consulting/fc4sc/tree/master/docs/FC4SC_User_Guide.pdf

Comment: @KamilCuk My question is that it cannot compile this I wonder if does anyone could see and give a solution for this. The command is in the page 13 too of https://github.com/amiq-consulting/fc4sc/blob/master/docs/FC4SC_User_Guide.pdf. And the following is the library https://github.com/amiq-consulting/fc4sc

Comment: Cool. So are you on windows with cygwin? Do you have `/usr/bin/cc` executable? Can you compile any C program on youe cygwin?

Comment: > Do you have /usr/bin/cc executable? Yes, I have it. > Can you compile any C program on youe cygwin? Yes, it work well too, and I make this make it available to use FC4SC library(functional coverage for systemC library), and of course the source code has to be worked well before using this library